# Blurred text *during* css transform - Chrome

Tags: css, transform

Hello I've been fighting with this for a while. I have a button (happens even with a div w/ text inside) that I'm trying to transform just slightly. During the transform the text shows blurry then kind of pops back into focus. Is there any way to just have the text stay the same size?? Or have it render during the transform??

I've tried the `rotate(0.02deg)` as you can see below. Also tried `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px)` AND `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` none of which give me just a smooth text transition in chrome.

```
    .smooth-pop:hover {   
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1) rotate(0.02deg);     
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.02deg);        
}
```

Viewing the code snippet below gives an idea of what is happening. This contains  all of my CSS for this functionality as well. It seems to be OK in IE.

```css
.smooth-pop {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  /*-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;*/
}
.smooth-pop::after {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .20);
  content: "";
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
.smooth-pop:hover {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.02deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.02deg);
  /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .20);*/
}
.smooth-pop:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="smooth-pop" style="width:50px; height:50px; border:1px solid black">
  test
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to using the CSS transform property.
Using it blurs the element for a better transition i'd suggest transforming the width and height of you're box instead of using the transform property.

Comment: Hey Dylan, thanks for the suggestion but it's not giving the desired effect, it doesn't pop up during the transition, it slides out and down when I use a transition on the height / widths. Again this is working in IE

Comment: I've just tested it on IE as well and it still gets blurred on IE so...

Comment: yea, but that's different, if you look at it in chrome it "pops" at the end, in IE it's still a smooth transition.

Comment: Alright well take a look at this pen I just made is this what you require ?
[http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRApJZ](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRApJZ)

Comment: noo sorry i've edited it to show what I'm looking for, (still exhibits the issue I'm running into though) compare the two, you will see the difference in movement: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRzGEK

Comment: Just tinker around with the width/height and speed of the transition.
[http://codepen.io/dylanwijnen1/pen/LRApJZ](http://codepen.io/dylanwijnen1/pen/LRApJZ)